# Fast Levenshtein Distance calculation against large list

Tags: python, list, bigdata, levenshtein-distance

I have a reference list of 90,000 strings in a text file. The strings all have a length of 15 chars.

Now I want to compare about 2 million strings with length 14-16 to the reference list. I want to calculate the Levenshtein-Distance (Edit-Distance) and get the best hit as well as its distance.
Or different -- the hits have to be of distance 0 or 1 and every larger distance is considered "no hit", this might be a way for potential speed up?

I want to do this in Python (ideally, but not necessarily if another solution like C is needed). I am aware of implementations in Python (like here: https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-distance) but I fear that this is too slow if I use this function on every comparison.

Comment: "I fear that this is too slow if I use this function on every comparison." Don't be afraid to try. Just code it up and let it run. See how long it takes to complete for a more reasonably sized subset, or see what percentage completes in a reasonable time.

Comment: What specifically is your question about this?

Comment: If you add test data (input and expected output) and *some* implementation, no matter how slow, you'd get a better response. (It's btw pretty simple, but without provided test data and reference code, at least I won't bother doing this.)

Comment: Michael, I tried several python modules, and this one (python-Levenshtein) is the fastest. I am using it with pdist, but it is overall too slow for a large number of strings like yours (and mine).